# оптимизация работы с API

Tags: php, json, api, оптимизация

Есть сайт, при загрузке одной страницы идут несколько десятков одинаковых запросов к апи(/api/products, /api/objects), нужно сделать оптимизацию запросов к апи, т.е. уменьшить количество одинаковых запросов.

Чтобы это сделать, думаю, нужно сохранить где-то несколько массивов JSON, которые вовзращает АПИ (весом примерно 1мб.), чтобы не ломиться к апи за одними и теми же данными.

Важно, что данные нужно обрабатывать на стороне сервера (php).

Пробовал сохранить в localstorage, но мне нужно еще и обработать эти данные, и получить их обратно на сервер при загрузке текущей страницы не получается.

Сохранять в сессиях думаю, что не очень хорошо будет.

Comment: вопрос сформулируйте, пожалуйста, нажав [edit] («кто что посоветует?» — это совсем неподходящий вопрос для данного сайта — см. справку)

Comment: Не совсем понятна проблема, как-то перемешано описание проблемы и видение решения проблемы.

Comment: Проблемма в то, что при открывании 100 страниц, к апи идут 10000 запросов, что не очень хорошо. Нужно уменшить обращения к апи. Так как много одинаковых запросов,и соответственно ответов,  подумал можно сделать два-три запроса и сохранить ответы (массивы где-то). Вопрос только где? Ведь нужно еще потом ответы(массивы) на сервере обрабатывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам поможет кеширование. Их бывает два вида.

### Клиентское кеширование

Давайте кешировать запросы на 1 час прямо в браузере? Тогда добавьте такой заголовок:

```
$maxAge = 3600;
header(sprintf('Cache-Control: max-age=%d, must-revalidate', $maxAge));
```

Проверить можно в Хроме через консоль разработчика - вкладка сеть, фильтр XHR. Закешированные запросы будут показываться как `(from disk cache)`.

Этот заголовок также можно добавить на уровне веб-сервера. В Nginx: `add_header Cache-Control "max-age=3600";`.

### Серверное кеширование

В принципе, клиентское кеширование спасет от кучи однотипных запросов. Однако если запросы идут от разных клиентов (разные люди в разных браузерах), включите кеширование на сервере.

В примере ниже игнорируется заголовок `Set-Cookie`. Это заставляет кешировать ответы для всех запросов, игнорируя авторизацию (не учитывается пользователь) и прочее. Если не уверены в том, что делаете, не используйте :) Удачное решение, если информация по продуктам / ценам одинакова для всех.

Чтобы лучше разбираться в отдельных тонкостях, отсылаю к [официальной документации](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/)

Так как я люблю nginx, пример будет для него:

```
# Настройки кеша
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx   # путь
  levels=1:2                  # количество уровней
  keys_zone=my_cache:10m      # название:размер зоны, 1Мб ~ 8000 ключей (1 ключ - 1 запрос)
  max_size=10g                # размер данных кеша, при превышении удаляются наиболее старые
  inactive=60m                # время хранения запроса на диске с момента последнего обращения, независимо от Cache-Control
  use_temp_path=off;          # off - используем proxy_cache_path; on - используем proxy_temp_path, указанный в location

server {

  # тут настройки вашего веб-сервера


  # укажите тут свой location, который следует кешировать
  location /api/ {

    # Какой кеш использовать? Эта инструкция работает также на уровне server
    proxy_cache my_cache;

    # Так можно будет в браузере понять, взят ли запрос диска, или пришлось запустисть веб-сервер
    # HIT - из кеша, MISS - с сервера, EXPIRED - время кеширования истекло, взято с сервера
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

    # Начинаем игнорировать заголовки:
    # Expires - точно нужно игнорировать, иначе не будет кешироваться, на счет остальных - не уверен
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie;

    # Добавляем свой Cache-Control
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=3600";

    # форсируем кеширование, хотя эта опция нужна не для всех случаев !!!
    proxy_cache_valid any 60m;

    # Если источник "отвалился", будем отдавать с диска
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

    # но будем обновляться в фоне, (c версии Nginx 1.11.10), если ваш Nginx старый, закомментируйте
    proxy_cache_background_update on;

    # Веб-сервер - источник данных
    proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
  }
}
```

UPD

Кеширование - палка о двух концах. Данные устаревают. Важно понять причины устаревания данных, типичную продолжительность их жизни и выработать стратегию инвалидации кеша.

Если указать срока жизни кеша в 1 час, это значит, что мы осознано идем на то, что данные могут быть просрочены на 1 час. Для описательной части товара это я считаю приемлемым.
Отзывы о товаре - нет (человек только что оставил отзыв, и его не видит).

Добавление параметра GET позволяет полностью инвалидировать кеш.

Допустим, вы обновляете каталог раз в сутки. Тогда новый URI будет содержать дату `/api/products?d=15012018`.

Если вы обновляете свой API с возможной "поломкой" обратной совместимости, добавьте версию API: `/api/products?v=0.101`.

Если кеш совершенно не приемлем, а запрос обрабатывается долго, смотрите в сторону ускорения производительности (в том числе оптимизации и кеширование отдельных SQL запросов, etc) и балансировки потока запросов на несколько веб-серверов.

Comment: Предлагая кэширование в качестве решения какой-либо проблемы, необходимо всегда упоминать проблему инвалидации кэша и предлагать пути её решения. В противном случае любой подобный совет принесет куда больше вреда, чем пользы.

Comment: @Ипатьев, проблему обозначил, если есть что добавить, пишите

Comment: API обновляется редко (раз в год примерно), также и редко меняется информация, которую отдает API (раз в месяц).

Comment: Если быть точнее, мне нужно закешировать список городов, что не есть приватной информацией, ну и редко меняющейся.

Comment: @AndriiGolovko, оба мои варианта позволяют это сделать. Выставите время кеширования 2 недели. Сильно увеличивать - бессмысленно, люди банально чистят кеш. Проще всего кешировать на клиенте. Если данные ходят по HTTP, они могут также кешироваться на промежуточных проксях, что может привести к проблеме на неправильной настроенной сети предприятия (есть опыт, когда шлюз предприятия отдавал старые данные, хотя там явно было прописано не кешировать). HTTPS не проксях не кешируется. Также см заголовок [private](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Directives)

Comment: На данный момент кеш настроен таким образом: на сервере создается по каждому из запросов файл, при обращении к апи данные беруться с него, если файла нет то с сервера. (phpfastcache). Но повотрюсь, что этот вариант себя исчерпал, так как выросло количество запросов к апи, соответственно сервер сам себя ддосит(((.

Comment: @AndriiGolovko, я предложил 2 варианта. Они не подходят?

Comment: Буду пробовать, отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: Если для каждого товара идет 1 запрос к `/api/products`, и таких запросов на странице сотни, группируйте в один. Посмотрите что такое REST, RESTful API. В вашем случае `/api/products/` должен вернуть все продукты. `/api/products/0b474221-4e7d-4482-9fbd-8f7406345e23` - товар с соответствующим guid. `/api/products/?state=new` - только новинки.

Answer (score 0):

> Есть сайт, при загрузке одной страницы идут несколько десятков одинаковых запросов

Вместо десятков одинаковых запросов к /api/products надо сделать один запрос, который возвращает десятки значений.

Повторить то же самое для /api/objects. Проблема решена.

Comment: А будет ли правильно хранить полученные данные от АПИ, напоминаю, что это массивы с данными (список городов) в сессиях? Ведь во время отрабатывания текущей страницы, нужно обращаться к етим данным несколько раз и на следующих страницах также. Какое решение можно применить? Если закешировать саму страницу АПИ, все равно огромное количество запросов к закешировнному файлу делает нагрузку.